# Atbeginsection returns missing number treated as zero

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to add a simple AtBeginSection() in my code so that the table of contents appears before every slide, however it returns a error that ! Missing number, treated as zero.
 }. See the code yourself

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{Simulation of Lunar Rover}
\subtitle{Complete}
\author{John Doe}

\institute{National University of Sciences and Technology H-12}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\AtBeginSection{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}}
\begin{frame}
\section{Problem statement}
\section{Existing results}
\subsection{Method 1}
\subsection{Method 2}
\subsection{Method 3}
\section{Comparative study}
\section*{References}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Sorry if the mistake is obvious, I am experienced with LaTeX but just started using beamer yesterday.

Comment: I can't test now but one thing looks fishy: you are calling `\section` *within* a `{frame}`, which will result in nested frames. That's definitely wrong.

Comment: Like @campa already said, you have to place all your `\section` and `\subsection` commands outside of frames. Making this modification, your code works as expected.

Comment: thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, it worked.

Comment: @campa Would you like to post an answer? I was so sure this would be a duplicate, but I fail to find a suitable dupe target.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done `:-)`

Comment: @campa :thumbsup:

Answer (score 2):

Sectioning commands must be given *outside* of frames (see `beamer` doc §3.7). If you use `\AtBeginSection` to print a frame (an absolutely legitimate use) but then call `\section` within a `{frame}`, then you'll be in fact nesting frames, and chaos will ensue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% [...]

\AtBeginSection{%
   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection]
   \end{frame}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


% \begin{frame} <------------------- NO !
\section{Problem statement}
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Existing results}
\subsection{Method 1}
\subsection{Method 2}
\subsection{Method 3}
\section{Comparative study}
\section*{References}
%\end{frame} <------------------- NO !
\end{document}
```